# Handling inbound and outbound CTI calls in my org

Tags: cti, twilio

I am looking into handling inbound and outbound calling in my org. We tried [Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/salesforce-integration#configure-salesforce-for-open-cti) earlier, but it didn't meet our requirements on the CRM side.

Everything that I have looked at involves writing more custom code than I should be, or it doesn't work. The twilio-salesforce docs that Twilio includes doesn't exist on the documentation website (https://readthedocs.org/projects/twilio-salesforce/downloads/pdf/stable/)

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this the documentation you are looking for to set up the [Flex-Salesforce CTI integration](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/salesforce-integration)? (Note: the documentation lists the feature as being in beta release.)

Comment: @MarkPond sorry for the wait on this. That was the document I originally looked at, but it seems like the integration wouldn't leverage the CRM in the way we would like it to.

Comment: @ConnorMcIntyre Was this solved for you ?